# Python pint: setting adimensional constants

Tags: python, pint

Let's suppose I have a program where the user get have values of a certain dimension (e.g. length) but different units.

The peculiarity is that some of those units (`scalefactor` and `hubble`) are actually adimensional constant

```
from pint import UnitRegistry
u = UnitRegistry()
u.define('mylength = kpc*scalefactor/hubble'); 


#... later in the code...

u.define('hubble = 0.704')
u.define('scalefactor = 0.93')
```

Then to convert a unit from `mylength` to `kpc` I did :

```
In [29]: (u.mylength*1.0).to(u.kpc)
Out[29]: <Quantity(1.0, 'kiloparsec')>
```

**But the output shouldn't be one**! because `mylength` divided by `kpc` is `scalefactor/hubble` that is `0.93/.704`  that is `1.32`.

**So, my question is**: how can I handle units that depends on constants that are defined only later in the code?

To be more precise:

```
In [1]: from pint import UnitRegistry
In [2]: u = UnitRegistry()
In [3]: u.define('mydist = kpc*scalefactor/hubble')
In [4]: u.define("scalefactor=0.9")
In [5]: u.define("hubble=0.704")
In [6]: float(u.mydist/u.kpc)
Out[6]: 1.0 #<-- I excepcted 1.32 instead of one!
```